# VS 2013 error C2664 when trying to compile a .c file as .cpp

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

I am on my way of programming my first external for Max 6, but the entitled error is holding me back. I have crawled for a week the web to find a solution to the entitled problem, but no luck. There are many topics related to

```
error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'X' to 'Y'
```

but none of the proposed solutions was suitable for my case, since it seems to be a Max object case-specific.

More to the point, I have a main .c file for my external that makes use of various other .cpp files and libraries. For that reason I want to compile it as a .cpp file. As far as I know, there shouldn't be a problem with that. However, when I am trying to compile it in Visual Studio I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 't_object *object_alloc(t_object *,const char *,...)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'void *' to 't_object *' "
```

Has anyone faced and managed to solve any similar issue? Is it the case that I am missing something more profound?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Paste your code here would help

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: Some humble soul, give it an edit ...

Answer (score 3):

C++, unlike C, does not permit implicit conversion of a void pointer to a non-void pointer. It seems that you are trying to pass a void pointer as the first argument to that function, but since it can't be converted to the parameter type, an error occurs.

You can solve this by casting the void pointer directly to the target pointer type.

```
object_alloc(static_cast<t_object*>(p), ...)
```

(FYI, the conversion in the reverse direction---non-void pointer to void pointer---is a standard conversion and can occur implicitly. `static_cast` is allowed to perform the *reverse* of standard conversion sequences.)

Comment: The `static_cast` won't compile as C. And the idea of a C file that can only be compiled as C++ seems... Well, meaningless.

Comment: Not any more ridiculous than trying to compile C with a C++ compiler :-P

Comment: Compiling C as C++ is the only way to get a useful subset of C99 with MSVC.

Answer (score 2):

In C there is an implicit conversion from `void*` to any data pointer type.

Together with C's implicit function declarations this means that in C it's not a good idea to cast the result of e.g. `malloc`, because with a missing header (no `malloc` declaration) that will implicitly declare `malloc` with result type `int`, and at least the local code will compile with no visible error... :(

In C++ there is no implicit conversion *from* `void*`.

So in C++ one not only should but most often must cast the result of e.g. `malloc`.

Happily C++ does not have implicit function declarations. :)

---

A good solution for your specific problem may be to compile the C file as C (duh).

However, be aware that the top level control of a combined C and C++ program, should better be C++. I.e. compile `main` as C++. That's because C++ has some extra runtime library requirements such as dynamic initialization of things.

Instead of an implementation file that can compile as either C or C++, consider just a header (with only pure declarations) that can be used with both languages. This is the common way to do things. You can use a conditional `extern "C"` to make the declarations work fine also in C++.